# FORTRAN: Use character as changeable array name

Tags: arrays, fortran, character

I am trying to write a subroutine to access arrays in a certain manner.
One input argument of the subroutine is a character containing the name of the array whose access is desired. Here is a rather simplified code example of how I generally imagine this to work:

```
PROGAM prog
real, dimension(3,3) :: array1(3,3)
real, dimension(3,3) :: array2(3,3)
real value1
real value2
... fill 'array1' and 'array2'...
call sub(array1,2,2,value1)
call sub(array2,2,2,value2)
... do something with 'value1' and 'value2'...
END

SUBROUTINE sub(name,x,y,out)
character(len=*), intent(in) :: name
integer, intent(in) :: x
integer, intent(in) :: y
real, intent(out) :: out
out = name(x,y)
RETURN
END
```

What I want is the subroutine to access `array1(2,2)` as requested in the argument and return this value to `value1`. Then access `array2(2,2)` and return this value to `value2`. Above code snippet does not work - no wonder about that. How do I get `name(x,y)` replaced with `array1(x,y)` respectively `array2(x,y)`?

Thanks a lot and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the name of the array to get at its content, if the array is declared in caller. You then use normal argument association.

You could write your subroutine as

```
subroutine sub(a,x,y,out)
  integer, intent(in) :: x, y
  real, intent(out) :: out
  real, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: a
  out = a(x,y)
end subroutine sub
```

Much simpler would be to do, in the main program

```
value1 = array1(2,2)
value2 = array2(2,2)
```

I would recommend a textbook on Fortran, or even a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features .

**Edit:**

You could also use a SELECT CASE statement, like this:

```
  subroutine bar(c, i, j, out)
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: c
    integer, intent(in) :: i,j
    real, intent(out) :: out

    select case (trim(c))
      case ("array1")
         out = array1(i,j)
      case ("array2")
         out = array2(i,j)
      case default
         stop "Argument is bletchful"
      end case
  end subroutine bar
```

I am simply at a loss to understand what good this would do, as opposed to using the array directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the point of the subroutine is to be able to access any array by a name given in the argument. A declaration in the caller is not possible and nor is a standard access in the main program. The code snippet is very simplified and should only illustrate the general problem.

Comment: Where, then, is the array in question declared?

Comment: It is declared allocatable in a module, than allocated in some other subroutine. I just need a way to get a character string converted such that I can use it to adress an array with the same name as the content of the character string.

Comment: Can you edit your example so it shows what you actually want to do, including the module structure?

Comment: It does not really make a difference how and where the array is declared. It is solely about the subroutine, that is supposed to get a character as an input and use this character to access an (already declared and filled) array that has the same name as the content of the character. Depending on the inputted character, different arrays can be accessed. I am sorry if the code snippet did not make this clear.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But still, I do not think that this is what I am looking. Imagine having several arrays. On runtime I decide what array I want to access by inputting a character variable. This character variable is used to access an array having the same name as the content of the character variable. I do not want to use precoded case instructions or something like that. How can I tell Fortran to use the content of the character string as the name of the array?

Comment: In standard Fortran, you cannot take a text string and convert it into a variable name. You will have to do something like the `SELECT CASE` above, or use a hash table, or a linked list, or whatever. The `SELECT CASE` method is the most straightforward one. Fortran is a typical compiled language in that respect; it does not have a construct like Perl's `eval`. You could also start playing around with compilation of extra code and dynamic linking, but I seriously doubt that you want to go down that road; it is certainly outside the scope of the language.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I think that is it. Although it is not exactly what I wanted to hear. I will then alter the concept of the code/subroutine to make it work with the case instructions or hash tables, etc. Thanks again for your time and sorry that the question was not completely clear in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select case (array_name)
   case ("array_dog")
      array_ptr => array_dog
   case ("array_cat")
      array_ptr => array_cat
end select
```

where `array_name` is a character variable, `array_dog` and `array_cat` are arrays declared in the module (needing `target` attribute), and `array_ptr` is another array with the `pointer` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not think that this is what I am looking. Imagine having several arrays. On runtime I decide what array I want to access by inputting a character variable. This character variable is used to access an array having the same name as the content of the character variable. I do not want to use precoded case instructions or something like that. How can I tell Fortran to use the content of the character string as the name of the array?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have Fortran convert the contents of a character string to become the name of a variable.

Comment: tkoenig wrote that in the other answer. I guess will use the case instructions then and alter the concept of the program as there is no other option. Thank you very much for your answers and your time.